# Windows 10: Missing Sounds, Playback & Recording Devices menu items when right click on speaker icon

Tags: windows-10

Windows 10 here with version:

```
>systeminfo.exe | grep "OS Version"
OS Version:                10.0.18362 N/A Build 18362
```

When using Right Mouse Buttom (RMB) on speaker icon it shows:

[image]

Which does not show `Sounds` or `Playback|Recording Devices` as these images that I got from the Net:

[image]
[image]

I can see those in other Windows 10 machine with `10.0.16299 N/A Build 16299`.

How can I bring those back?

Answer (score 4):

Clicking on `Open Sound Settings` brings this windows:

[image]

And then clicking on `Sound Control Panel` the required panel appears:

[image]

Other way to bring it directly is to use <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, and then:

```
control mmsys.cpl
```

or

```
control.exe /name Microsoft.Sound
```

or

```
explorer shell:::{F2DDFC82-8F12-4CDD-B7DC-D4FE1425AA4D}
```

All those taken from [this link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/shortcut-to-sound-control-panel/32d5a6e7-fa92-4ca7-9033-cd38ba525542).